# java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERInteger not found

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish, jpa-2.0, bouncycastle

I'm opening a prior application written in Java EE 7. My goal is to compile and run the app. I have tried several flavors of Netbeans and operating systems to get this done. The app compiles and runs fine in a stand alone Macbook Pro laptop using Netbeans 11.3. The Mac is just for testing.

The server environment is a Windows 2019 Server (v1809) and this is where I am having problems using both Netbeans v11.3 and 12.0. In both cases I get the same error. I also tried to build in JDK 1.7 and 1.8. Noticing the CanonialModelProcessor message in the stack trace, I am building in JDK 1.8.

> Compiling 203 source files to
> C:*********\build\web\WEB-INF\classes warning: Supported
> source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor
> 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor'
> less than -source '1.8' Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
> error: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file
> for org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERInteger not found
>
> An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception. Consult the
> following stack trace for details. java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
> org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERInteger not found    at
> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
> at
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
> at
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
> at
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
> at
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
> at
> com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
> at
> com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
> at
> com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
> at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)     at
> com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)  at
> com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)  at
> com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)  at
> com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:57)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1404)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1133)  at
> org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:120)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> java.util.Vector.forEach(Vector.java:1275)    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:67)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:391)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
> at
> org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
> Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class
> file for org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERInteger not found BUILD FAILED
> (total time: 10 seconds)

I researched a few similar questions on SOF and other online sources. I noticed bouncycastle libraries tend to be in more than one place. My questions are:

1. If this is really an error to do with bouncycastle is there a single jar of library that has all of the bouncycastle classes? In my app I added:

   ```
    lib\bcpkix-jdk15to18-168.jar lib\bcprov-ext-jdk15to18-1.68.jar
    lib\bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar lib\bc-fips-1.0.2.jar
    lib\bcmail-fips-1.0.3.jar lib\bcpkix-fips-1.0.5.jar
    lib\bcpkix-jdk15to18-168.jar
   ```
2. If it is not a bouncycastle error, any idea what is causing this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by rebuilding this as a Maven project, using trial and error and mostly just importing the most recent / updated dependencies. In cases where compile errors were observed, this was solved by importing the dependencies matching the close time stamps to when the application was originally written.